# Highcharts hide legend item from Pie chart

Tags: highcharts

I am looking to remove one of the legend item on runtime , Hiding using css results in blank space being created in the legend.

Fiddle Link - https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/pie-legend

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
chart: {
    plotBackgroundColor: null,
    plotBorderWidth: null,
    plotShadow: false,
    type: 'pie'
},
title: {
    text: 'Browser market shares in January, 2018'
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.percentage:.1f}%</b>'
},
accessibility: {
    point: {
        valueSuffix: '%'
    }
},
plotOptions: {
    pie: {
        allowPointSelect: true,
        cursor: 'pointer',
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.1f} %'
        }
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Brands',
    colorByPoint: true,
    data: [{
        name: 'Chrome',
        y: 61.41,
        sliced: true,
        selected: true
    }, {
        name: 'Internet Explorer',
        y: 11.84
    }, {
        name: 'Firefox',
        y: 10.85
    }, {
        name: 'Edge',
        y: 4.67
    }, {
        name: 'Safari',
        y: 4.18
    }, {
        name: 'Sogou Explorer',
        y: 1.64
    }, {
        name: 'Opera',
        y: 1.6
    }, {
        name: 'QQ',
        y: 1.2
    }, {
        name: 'Other',
        y: 2.61
    }]
}]
```

});

Idea is to not show "Others" in the legend and only the relevant legend items.

[image]

Please note:- I am only looking to hide very first Legend item along with its color index.

Comment: Your codepen link is broken FYI

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this custom code - it hides the last legend group element.

```
    events: {
        load() {
            const chart = this;
            const allLegendItems = chart.legend.allItems;
            
            allLegendItems[allLegendItems.length - 1].legendGroup.hide();
        }
    }
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/b40ysjgu/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.load